# Outlook Interop ClearSelection Method

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, interop

I am having difficulties with Interop in a WPF application.
What I actually want to do is drag and drop an Outlook file into my application and extract the attachments and store them. Apart from that I want to read the subject and search for a 4-digit-number which will then be the name of the folder the attachments are to be stored to.
I have been searching the web for solutions that don't use Interop, but I wasn't able to find anything that worked for me.
So I thought 'let's give it a shot' and it sounded pretty simple, because I found so many examples that followed this pattern:

```
 if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection selection = app.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

            foreach (object mi in selection)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mi;
                string subject = "Untitled";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.Subject))
                {
                    subject = mailItem.Subject;
                    MessageBox.Show(subject);
                }
            }

        }
```

This works, but I have one problem: the selection keeps on growing. I tried the methods RemoveFromSelection and ClearSelection, but they don't work. Everytime I drag a new Outlook item to the surface it keeps displaying all the previous items as well.
Can anybody help me? I'm at a complete loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you handle the Drag event in your application?

If so, try to call the following code in the event handler:

```
e.Data.GetData(“RenPrivateMessages”);
```

See [Outlook, custom task pane and drag-drop problem](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/26/outlook-task-pane-drag-drop/) for more information.

Comment: I've just come across some similar articles in German and I used a quite common hack. 
I just switch to a different folder in Outlook and back to the inbox. This works :)
Thank you!

Comment: Switching folders doesn't help to release COM objects. Also I'd recommend using the existing Outlook instance instead of creating a new one.

Comment: OK. So I just have to basically copy and paste that code bit into the event handlers of the drag event? But which drag event? Drag-Enter, Drag-Leave or the other one (don't know it right now :) )
And how would I use the existing Outlook instance and why?
Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Just try to add the code to the DragEnter event in your app. It should allow to avoid the issue with the selection object.